# ASP.NET Windows Authentication requesting user credentials repeatedly

Tags: asp.net, windows, authentication, deployment

I'm using a Base Page with the following code. In the Constructor, I'm populating all the properties of the BasePage class. All other content pages inherit from the BasePage class, but both before and after deploying the code in IIS, I'm prompted used credentials again and again. Below is the BasePage Constructor code.

```
public BasePage()
    {
        mybo = new UserBOL();
        mydata = new UserData();
        mydata = mybo.GetUserByESID(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToUpper().Split('\\')[1]);
        if (mydata == null)
            Response.Redirect("UnAuthorized.aspx");
    }
```

Sample Property of the BasePage:

```
public int Id
    {
        get 
        {
            _id = mydata.ID;
            return _id;
        }
        set { _id = value; }
    }
```

In IIS, I've enabled only Windows Authentication and disabled all the rest. Please help!

Comment: Are both computers (server, and client/browser) on the same Active Directory Domain? If not, the browser will prompt for credentials since windows wont pass through unless they're both on the same domain.

Comment: yes both, are in the same domain

Comment: Are you using the server name to access the site or are you using IP address or a custom domain? You may need to add the site to Intranet sites in Internet Explorer if the host name contains periods.

Comment: I'm using the server name to access the site.

Comment: Do you get the same prompt on a simple page that simply outputs the usernam? i.e. The only code on the page is `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToUpper().Split('\\')[1]`

Comment: One more observation is I'm getting this message only in IE and not in FireFox